# List of Weblogic Error Codes

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, error-code

**Context**

I have been debugging an Oracle Weblogic Server 10.3.0.0 JDBC Connection which is logging the error code:

> BEA-001112

After some searching around I found a bit of an explanation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10106/dbac.htm#BHCFFAJF

Although it does depend on the actual exception being thrown, I believe this means:
*there was an error when testing a new connection in the JDBC Connection Pool before handing it off to be used by the application.*

**Question**

Does anyone know of a list of Weblogic Error Codes that has a general description for the specific Error Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle portfolio [WebLogic](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/weblogic/index.html) is a part of [Oracle Fusion Middleware](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/index.html) (OFMW). Thus the error code (or message) list is a part of [OFMW documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/middleware.html).

As the links a quite difficult to find for uninitiated here's direct links to a few different releases.

- [WebLogic 10.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e14397/index.html)
- [WebLogic 10.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e14397/index.html)
- [WebLogic 12.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/FMERR/chapter_bea_messages.htm#sthref2268)

They are not much descriptive, but hopefully can give you at least an introduction. You can also index them by subsystem. Clicking on a message (or message range) will bring up the details.

Comment: That's what I was looking for thanks. I can't believe I didn't find it :/

Comment: @edwardTheGreat I had the same problem as you some time ago, and took a LONG time to find it out. Then, I've bookmarked it :)

Answer (score -1):

Cause: The specified data source connection pool has been configured with one or
more attributes to test the pool connections. One of those test attempts failed. The
associated error is printed.
Action: Check the associated error to see what the problem is and correct it.
Normally, this indicates that a connection was lost to the database (the database is
down). This needs to be corrected by the database administrator.